# Delphi 2010 forms shows on "wrong" monitor

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, multiple-monitors

I have a simple test app, with one empty form, and a second containing a TButton. The button script is like this:-

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Show();
end;
```

`Form2` is auto-created at startup. There's no other code at all.

When I run the app, I can press the button and `Form2` appears. I can reposition/resize `Form2` on the primary monitor, and then close it. If I press the `Form1` button again, `Form2` correctly reappears in the position it was last at. All fine so far...

However, if I position `Form2` onto a secondary monitor, close it, and then press the button, then `Form2` appears back on the primary monitor!

I want the form to reappear on the monitor it was last on - how can I get this behaviour??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because the default value for the form's [`DefaultMonitor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.DefaultMonitor) property is `dmActiveForm`.

Set Form2's `DefaultMonitor` to `dmDesktop`, and the problem is resolved.

Comment: You should give this answer the green check mark because it is correct.